# Looping over a variant

Tags: vba, excel

I am declaring these two variables in VBA

```
Dim MyInteger As Integer
Dim MyVariant As Variant
```

I would like bind a number to MyVariant so it numerically increments an integer value to a variant in the following manner:

```
MyVariant1 , MyVariant2, MyVariant3, MyVariant4, MyVariant5
```

I am trying to do this rather than having to declare hundreds of variants in the following way:

```
MyVariant As Variant
MyVariant1 As Variant 
MyVariant2 As Variant 
MyVariant3 As Variant 
MyVariant4 As Variant 
MyVariant5 As Variant
```

I am trying to do this using a for loop, but it does not seem to work

```
Dim MyInteger As Integer
Dim MyVariant As Variant
For MyInteger = 1 To 5
MyVariant & MyInteger
Next MyInteger
```

Comment: You can't do that in VBA. You could use an array `Dim MyVariant(1 to 5) As Variant`.

Comment: Or use a collection

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in detail?

Comment: Adding a number to a variant.  So that it loops like this: MyVariant1 , MyVariant2, MyVariant3, MyVariant4 and MyVariant5.

Comment: Then what?  Are you then going to loop through them and assign a value?

Comment: Nothing else. I simply need a loop that increments a number to a variant like this: MyVariant1 , MyVariant2, MyVariant3, MyVariant4 and MyVariant5

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? "MyVariant & MyInteger"  it is meaningless in VBA as written.  Also, MyVariant has no value, where MyInteger has the values 1 to 5.

Comment: Please see my edit.  I need to declare hundreds of variants with an incrementing integer value binded to them.

Comment: Unfortunately you saying you want to do something doesn't make it possible. It's a cruel world.

Comment: Use an Array like the first comment suggest.  It is the only way.

Comment: Could either you or SJR provide a short working example?

Comment: @codinglady, ... `Nothing else` ... your comments indicate that this may be for a school assignment. you should be talking to your teacher.

Comment: jsotola...I'm a grandmother.  What's your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just declare your `myVariant` as an array of variant variables.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim myInteger As Integer, myVariants(1 To 255) As Variant

    For myInteger = 1 To 255
        myVariants(myInteger) = "SomeValue"
    Next myInteger

End Sub
```

If you are unsure the number of variables you will need, you can go about it this way:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim myInteger As Long, myVariants() As Variant
    Dim NumberNeeded As Long

    NumberNeeded = 'Some value
    ReDim myVariants(1 To NumberNeeded)

    For myInteger = 1 To UBound(myVariants)
        myVariants(myInteger) = "SomeValue"
    Next myInteger

End Sub
```

Comment: Good, we need some code to clarify OP's objectives.